# Finding tokens in a Java String

Tags: java, string

Is there a nice way to extract tokens that start with a pre-defined string and end with a pre-defined string?

For example, let's say the starting string is "[" and the ending string is "]".  If I have the following string:

"hello[world]this[[is]me"

The output should be:

token[0] = "world"

token[1] = "[is"

(Note: the second token has a 'start' string in it)

Comment: Are your tokens one-character only or may them be longer ?

Comment: may be longer - my example was for simplicity however the start string could be "foo" and the end string could be "bar".

Comment: Looks like Apache Commons Lang - StringUtils.substringsBetween(string,open,close) is what you need.  Works as per above requirement, see answer below for more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can use the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) feature that exists in [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html):

```
substringsBetween(java.lang.String str,
                  java.lang.String open,
                  java.lang.String close)
```

The API docs say it:

> Searches a String for substrings
>   delimited by a start and end tag,
>   returning all matching substrings in
>   an array.

The Commons Lang substringsBetween API can be found here:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringsBetween(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way I would go to avoid dependency on commons lang.

```
public static String escapeRegexp(String regexp){
    String specChars = "\\$.*+?|()[]{}^";
    String result = regexp;
    for (int i=0;i<specChars.length();i++){
        Character curChar = specChars.charAt(i);
        result = result.replaceAll(
            "\\"+curChar,
            "\\\\" + (i<2?"\\":"") + curChar); // \ and $ must have special treatment
    }
    return result;
}

public static List<String> findGroup(String content, String pattern, int group) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        result.add(m.group(group));
    }
    return result;
}


public static List<String> tokenize(String content, String firstToken, String lastToken){
    String regexp = lastToken.length()>1
                    ?escapeRegexp(firstToken) + "(.*?)"+ escapeRegexp(lastToken)
                    :escapeRegexp(firstToken) + "([^"+lastToken+"]*)"+ escapeRegexp(lastToken);
    return findGroup(content, regexp, 1);
}
```

Use it like this :

```
String content = "hello[world]this[[is]me";
List<String> tokens = tokenize(content,"[","]");
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel though?

Comment: Because we live in a free world. And because you may not want to use a whole library for one method in it. And because I like it this way. Happy ?

Answer (score 0):

[StringTokenizer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)?Set the search string to "[]" and the "include tokens" flag to `false` and I think you're set.

Comment: Sorry, which method is this?  I don't see anything with something like 'include tokens' in the signature

Comment: I can't seem to find that in the docs either: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: It is in the 3-arguments constructor. Nonetheless, the result will be {"hello","[","world","]","this","[","[","is","]","me"} so additional work needs to take place.

Answer (score 0):

Normal string tokenizer wont work for his requirement but you have to tweak it or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

There's one way you can do this.  It isn't particularly pretty.  What it involves is going through the string character by character.  When you reach a "[", you start putting the characters into a new token.  When you reach a "]", you stop.  This would be best done using a data structure not an array since arrays are of static length.

Another solution which may be possible, is to use regexes for the String's split split method.  The only problem I have is coming up with a regex which would split the way you want it to.  What I can come up with is {]string of characters[) XOR (string of characters[) XOR (]string of characters) Each set of parenthesis denotes a different regex.  You should evaluate them in this order so you don't accidentally remove anything you want.  I'm not familiar with regexes in Java, so I used "string of characters" to denote that there's characters in between the brackets.

Comment: yeah I was thinking that character-by-character may have to be the solution but was hoping to steer clear of that if possible - especially if there was an elegant pre-existing API for what I want already.

Answer (score 0):

Try a regular expression like:

```
(.*?\[(.*?)\])
```

The second capture should contain all of the information between the set of []. This will however not work properly if the string contains nested [].

Answer (score 0):

StringTokenizer won't cut it for the specified behavior.  You'll need your own method.  Something like:

```
public List extractTokens(String txt, String str, String end) {
    int                      so=0,eo;
    List                     lst=new ArrayList();

    while(so<txt.length() && (so=txt.indexOf(str,so))!=-1) {
        so+=str.length();
        if(so<txt.length() && (eo=txt.indexOf(end,so))!=-1) {
            lst.add(txt.substring(so,eo);
            so=eo+end.length();
            }
        }
    return lst;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression `\\[[\\[\\w]+\\]` gives us 
[world] and 
[[is]